# how can i scrape data which gets generated after "load more" is clicked and url remains unchanged?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Im trying to scrape all the courses available under a category or the whole website https://www.classcentral.com/subject .However,the website only shows 55 courses at once(including ads) and you have to click the load more button which generates 50 more courses and so on.i used selenium for clicking the load more button and then called the parse_subject function on itself so as to yield the datapoints of the loaded courses.But the scraper keeps on scraping only the first 55 courses indefinitely.how do i make scraper scrape the next set of 50 courses without scraping the first set again and again and keep doing this until there are no more courses?please help

Here's the code for the "load the next 50 courses of [total]"

```
<button id="show-more-courses" class="btn-blue-outline width-14-16 medium- 
up-width-1-2 btn--large margin-top-medium text-center" data-page="2" 
style="" data-track-click="listing_click" data-track-props="{ 
"type": "Load More Courses", "page": "2" }}">
   <span class="small-up-hidden text--bold">Load more</span>
   <span class="hidden small-up-inline-block text--bold">
              Load the next 50 courses of 1127
          </span>
</button>
```

here's my code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
class SubjectsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'subjects'
    allowed_domains = ['class-central.com']
    start_urls = ['http://class-central.com/subjects']

    def __init__(self,subject=None):
        self.subject=subject

    def parse(self, response):
        if self.subject:
            print("True")
            subject_url=response.xpath('//*[contains(@title, "'+  self.subject + '")]/@href').extract_first()
            yield Request(response.urljoin(subject_url),callback=self.parse_subject,dont_filter=True)
        else:
            self.logger.info('Scraping all subjects')
            subjects=response.xpath('//*[@class="unit-block unit-fill"]/a/@href').extract()
            for subject in subjects:
                self.logger.info(subject)
                yield Request(response.urljoin(subject), callback=self.parse_subject,dont_filter=True)


    def parse_subject(self,response):
        subject_name=response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
        subject_name=subject_name.split(' | ') [0]
        courses = response.xpath('//*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]')
        for course in courses:
            course_name = course.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
            course_url = course.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="url"]/@href').extract_first()
            absolute_course_url = response.urljoin(course_url)

            yield{
            'subject_name':subject_name,
            'course_name':course_name,
            'absolute_course_url':absolute_course_url,
        }
    #for loading more courses
        global driver #declared global so that browser window does not close after finishing request.
        driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/webdrivers/chromedriver')
        driver.get(response.url)
        print(driver.current_url)
        try:
            button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('show-more-courses')
        #button_element.click()
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button_element)
            yield Request(response.url,callback=self.parse_subject,dont_filter=True)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should only use selenium if there is not solution with requests. The requests library is a lot faster and more reliable. Here is some code that loops through all the pages, then you can use Beautiful Soup to parse through the html. You will need to install Beautiful Soup however before using it if you want to.

---

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1, 10): #Change 10 to however many times you need to press "Load Next 50 Courses"
    params={'page': str(page)}
    next_page = requests.get("https://www.classcentral.com/subject/cs", params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(next_page.text, 'html.parser')
    #Parse through html
```